# Is it safe to move a tokio::net::TcpStream across different runtime instances?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to make a server for a game and was thinking of having multiple shards running on different threads. Each thread would have a `current_thread` runtime. My question is: is it safe to move a TcpStream from one runtime to another so players could move between said shards?

This rises from having low understanding of the tokio runtime internals. If I were to use C, each thread would need its own epoll/iocp instance and sockets would need to be added/removed as they are moved from one thread to another. This makes me think that it's not a trivial task and doing so could lead to bugs (perhaps subtle and hard to find).

On the other hand, if it uses linux's iouring where operations are queued and sockets don't need to be registered, then it could be a simple matter but I'm not sure that is the case (because it also needs to support windows IOCP somehow?).

I made this small server application to test whether it was even possible and it not only compiled but also seems to have worked. I'm still paranoid as to how exactly these are handled internally so I'm not 100% convinced this is safe.

I have also scoured the tokio docs and found out that the `mpsc` channel can be used across runtimes (which is why it is used here) but didn't find the same information regarding sockets.

```rust
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt},
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
    sync::mpsc,
};

use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, hash_map::Entry},
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

struct TransferMap {
    inner: Mutex<HashMap<u64, mpsc::UnboundedSender<TcpStream>>>,
}

impl TransferMap {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { inner: Mutex::new(HashMap::new()) }
    }

    fn add_tx(&self, tx: mpsc::UnboundedSender<TcpStream>) -> u64 {
        let mut inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        loop {
            let id = rand::random::<u64>();
            if let Entry::Vacant(entry) = inner.entry(id) {
                entry.insert(tx);
                return id;
            }
        }
    }

    fn transfer(&self, id: u64, s: TcpStream) {
        let inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        if let Some(tx) = inner.get(&id) {
            tx.send(s).unwrap();
        }
    }

    fn transfer_any(&self, s: TcpStream) {
        let inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        if inner.len() > 0 {
            let index = rand::random::<usize>() % inner.len();
            let tx = inner.values().nth(index).unwrap();
            tx.send(s).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn spawn_shard(map: &Arc<TransferMap>){
    let (connection_tx, connection_rx) = mpsc::unbounded_channel();
    let shard_id = map.add_tx(connection_tx);
    let map = map.clone();
    std::thread::Builder::new()
        .name(format!("shard#{shard_id}"))
        .spawn(move || shard_main(map, shard_id, connection_rx))
        .expect("failed to spawn shard thread");
}

fn server_run(map: Arc<TransferMap>) {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .expect("failed to create listener async runtime")
        .block_on(async {
            let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7777").await
                    .expect("failed to bind listener");
            println!("server listening on {}", listener.local_addr().unwrap());
            loop {
                match listener.accept().await {
                    Ok((s, _addr)) => map.transfer_any(s),
                    Err(e) => eprintln!("accept error {:?}", e),
                }
            }
        });
}

async fn shard_handle_connection(
            map: Arc<TransferMap>,
            shard_id: u64,
            mut s: TcpStream) {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
    match s.read(&mut buf).await {
        Ok(n) => {
            let message = std::str::from_utf8(&buf[..n]).unwrap_or("");
            println!("shard#{} message from {}: {}",
                    shard_id, s.peer_addr().unwrap(), message);

            if let Err(e) = s.write_all(&buf[..n]).await {
                eprintln!("connection write error: {e}");
            } else {
                map.transfer_any(s);
            }
        },
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("connection read error: {e}");
        },
    }
}

fn shard_main(map: Arc<TransferMap>, shard_id: u64,
            mut connection_rx: mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<TcpStream>) {
    tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .expect("failed to create shard async runtime")
        .block_on(async move {
            loop {
                match connection_rx.recv().await {
                    Some(s) => {
                        println!("shard#{} handling connection {}", shard_id, s.peer_addr().unwrap());
                        tokio::spawn(shard_handle_connection(map.clone(), shard_id, s));
                    },
                    None => {
                        println!("shard#{shard_id} closed");
                        break;
                    },
                }
            }

            // TODO(fusion): Transfer all connections to another shard?
        });
}

pub fn main() {
    let transfer_map = Arc::new(TransferMap::new());
    let nshards = std::thread::available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
    println!("spawning {nshards} shards");
    for _ in 0..nshards {
        spawn_shard(&transfer_map);
    }
    server_run(transfer_map);
}
```

EDIT:

I did some extra research and stumbled upon another solution. This time I started by using `LocalSet` with the `current_thread` runtime to have a single threaded server.

Then, I learned I could `block_on` on the same `current_thread` runtime from multiple threads and they should all share the same io/timer drivers.

Combining these two, I got a solution that feels correct.

```rust
use std::{
    collections::{HashMap, hash_map::Entry},
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
};

use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt},
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
    runtime::{Builder, Runtime},
    sync::mpsc,
    task,
};

struct TransferMap {
    inner: Mutex<HashMap<u64, mpsc::UnboundedSender<TcpStream>>>,
}

impl TransferMap {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { inner: Mutex::new(HashMap::new()) }
    }

    fn add_tx(&self, tx: mpsc::UnboundedSender<TcpStream>) -> u64 {
        let mut inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        loop {
            let id = rand::random::<u64>();
            if let Entry::Vacant(entry) = inner.entry(id) {
                entry.insert(tx);
                return id;
            }
        }
    }

    fn transfer(&self, id: u64, s: TcpStream) {
        let inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        if let Some(tx) = inner.get(&id) {
            tx.send(s).unwrap();
        }
    }

    fn transfer_any(&self, s: TcpStream) {
        let inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        if inner.len() > 0 {
            let index = rand::random::<usize>() % inner.len();
            let tx = inner.values().nth(index).unwrap();
            tx.send(s).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

async fn shard_handle_connection(
            map: Arc<TransferMap>,
            shard_id: u64,
            mut s: TcpStream){
    let addr = s.peer_addr().unwrap();
    println!("shard#{} handling connection {:?}", shard_id, addr);

    let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
    for _ in 0..5 {
        match s.read(&mut buf).await {
            Ok(n) => {
                let message = std::str::from_utf8(&buf[..n]).unwrap_or("");
                println!("shard#{} message from {:?}: {}", shard_id, addr, message);
                if let Err(err) = s.write_all(message.as_bytes()).await {
                    println!("shard#{} connection {:?} write error: {}", shard_id, addr, err);
                    return;
                }
            },
            Err(err) => {
                println!("shard#{} connection {:?} read error: {}", shard_id, addr, err);
                return;
            },
        }
    }

    map.transfer_any(s);
}

async fn shard_main(map: Arc<TransferMap>, shard_id: u64,
            mut connection_rx: mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<TcpStream>) {
    loop {
        match connection_rx.recv().await {
            Some(s) => {
                task::spawn_local(shard_handle_connection(Arc::clone(&map), shard_id, s));
            },
            None => {
                println!("shard#{shard_id} closed");
                break;
            },
        }

        // TODO(fusion): Transfer all connections to another shard?
    }
}

fn spawn_shard(rt: Arc<Runtime>, map: Arc<TransferMap>){
    let (connection_tx, connection_rx) = mpsc::unbounded_channel();
    let shard_id = map.add_tx(connection_tx);
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let local = task::LocalSet::new();
        local.block_on(&rt, shard_main(map, shard_id, connection_rx));
    });
}

pub fn main() {
    let map = Arc::new(TransferMap::new());
    let rt = Arc::new(Builder::new_current_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .build()
        .expect("failed to create async runtime"));

    let nshards = std::thread::available_parallelism().unwrap().get();
    for _ in 0..nshards {
        spawn_shard(Arc::clone(&rt), Arc::clone(&map));
    }

    rt.block_on(async move {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7777").await
                .expect("failed to bind listener");
        loop {
            match listener.accept().await {
                Ok((s, _addr)) => map.transfer_any(s),
                Err(err) => println!("accept error: {:?}", err),
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you use a different runtime than `current_thread`, the objects are shared between the threads, so this should not be an issue. But I don't know about the question of sharing objects between runtimes. Why do you not just run it with tokio from the beginning and then use a runtime with the size of CPUs available. If you need more separated runtimes, you could start multiple processes.

Comment: The idea was to have each shard running on its own thread so it wouldn't need to synchronize access to local shard data. Having a single muli-thread runtime is also possible but I'd need to have a mutex wrapping shard data to prevent two threads from handling a task from the same shard simultaneously.

In the small test I posted, there is no shard data but in the real application it would have an internal state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Tokio TcpStream will use the epoll instance of the runtime it was created in. If you use it in a different runtime, then it will work as long as the original runtime is still active, but it will be less performant since wakeups still happen on the original runtime, incurring cross-thread-communication costs.

To reregister a TcpStream to a different runtime, you can turn it into an `std::net::TcpStream` and back using `into_std` and then `from_std`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to converting the socket into `std::net::TcpStream` and back as described in the first answer, you can use the [`runtime::Handle::enter()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Handle.html#method.enter) to register the socket correctly when creating it. Of course, that requires you to have the runtime's handle available at that point, but at least that allows to create the socket initially on a different thread and runtime than the one that will own it.

Note, however, that when an `EnterGuard` lives across a suspension point (an `await` expression), any other tasks that are polled on that thread after the current task has been suspended and before it resumes, will see current runtime as the one set by the `EnterGuard`. Consider the following code:

```rust
let guard = my_runtime_handle.enter();
let socket = TcpStream::connect(remote_addr).await?;
drop(guard);
```

If any tasks running on the same thread, call `runtime::Handle::current()` while the socket is connecting, it will return `my_runtime_handle`. Furthermore, if any of those tasks try to enter a runtime using `EnterGuard` you will need to make sure the guards are dropped in the reverse order as they were created, otherwise the application will panic.

> Then, I learned I could block_on on the same current_thread runtime
> from multiple threads and they should all share the same io/timer
> drivers.

The sockets registered on the runtime will indeed share the same io drivers. However, only one of the threads will be polling them. Here is what the [documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Runtime.html#method.block_on) says:

> When the current thread scheduler is enabled block_on can be called
> concurrently from multiple threads. The first call will take ownership
> of the io and timer drivers. This means other threads which do not own
> the drivers will hook into that one. When the first block_on
> completes, other threads will be able to “steal” the driver to allow
> continued execution of their futures.

In other words, this doesn't guarantee that a socket's io drivers will run on the same thread as the socket itself. So this solution doesn't alleviate the overhead of cross-thread communication.